# QueryFailedError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am modifying a TypeOrm entity, and I broke the code somehow, but it's very difficult to get what's wrong.

All I have as a error message is :

> [Nest] 31328   - 21/12/2021, 15:15:05   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +269ms
>
> QueryFailedError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'array NOT NULL, `sessionId` varchar(36) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 1
>
> at QueryFailedError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
> at new QueryFailedError (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
> at Query.onResult (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/src/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.ts:183:37)
> at Query.execute (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:36:14)
> at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
> at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
> at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
> at Socket. (/Users/arthurmehmetoglu/Development/CorpoSano/back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)

Any idea how could get more information on what TypeOrm is trying to perform here?

EDIT: After reading carefully the error message, the only clue is that the `sessionId` is causing some trouble for some reason.

So I am sharing here are the entities that potentially involved:

```
@Entity()
export class Session extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => Workout, (workout) => workout.sessions)
  workout: Workout

  @OneToMany(() => Performance, (performance) => performance.session, {
    eager: true,
  })
  performances: Performance[]

  constructor(partial: Partial<Session> = {}) {
    super()
    Object.assign(this, partial)
  }
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Performance extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => Session, (session) => session.performances)
  session: Session

  @Column('int', { array: true })
  sets: number[]

  constructor(partial: Partial<Performance> = {}) {
    super()
    Object.assign(this, partial)
  }
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Workout extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  title: string

  @ManyToOne(() => Program, (program) => program.workouts)
  program?: Program

  @OneToMany(() => Exercise, (exercise) => exercise.workout, { eager: true })
  exercises?: Exercise[]

  @OneToMany(() => Session, (session) => session.workout)
  sessions?: Session[]

  @Column({
    type: 'set',
    enum: WeekDays,
    default: [],
  })
  scheduledDays?: WeekDays[]

  constructor(partial: Partial<Workout> = {}) {
    super()
    Object.assign(this, partial)
  }
}
```

Comment: `ARRAY` is not a data type supported by MySQL. Perhaps you have TypeOrm configured to generate SQL for some other flavor of database? Perhaps PostgreSQL, which does support `ARRAY` as a data type?

Comment: I am not sure it's related as TypeOrm should manage that for me as far as I understand.

Yet I have edited my post to give more informations with my understandings.

Comment: I'm not a TypeOrm user, but I assume you need to define `"type":"mysql"` in your [ormconfig.json file](https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig) so it knows what SQL features are supported by the respective brand of database. I am guessing you have not set that type property, or set it to "postgres".

Comment: The abstraction layer is trying to hide the SQL implementation from you.  Alas, instead it requires you to understand _both_ the abstraction (TypeOrm) _and_ the underlying (MySQL) languages.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying the `Performance` entity as follow:

```
@Entity()
export class Performance extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => Session, (session) => session.performances)
  session: Session

  @Column('simple-array')
  sets: number[]

  constructor(partial: Partial<Performance> = {}) {
    super()
    Object.assign(this, partial)
  }
}
```